# Split and color the duplicate row value if the defect status is ready to retest, using VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel, macros

[image]Rewording based on the Comment.

1.If the status in F column = ready to retest or passed

2.then if there are any values in Column C, take/split the Duplicate ID in column C separated with comma(,)

3.search the duplicate id in Column A and mark it with Green color

ex. In Row 1 for the defect ID  JIRA1 there are 2 duplicate id ALM3 and ALM7. so i need to look for those values in Column A. 4.If the status of those defects (ALM3 and ALM7) is NOT closed then i need to mark the entire row in Green color

Sub findduplicateColoreIt()

```
'Get the last row
Dim Report As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer

Set Report = Excel.Worksheets("Sheet2")                                       
lastRow = Report.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 2 To lastRow
    For j = 2 To lastRow
        If Report.Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" And Report.Cells(i, 7).Value = "Ready to retest" And Report.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Jira" Then 'This will omit blank cells at the end (in the event that the column lengths are not equal.
            If InStr(1, Report.Cells(j, 2).Value, Report.Cells(i, 3).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then


            ' need to get a logic where i need to get value from Colum D, split it and find the value in column A and color the row with green/any.
                a = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ",")


                Exit For
            Else
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: `not sure if this works`.  Well, it either does what you want or it does not.  What does it do that is wrong?

Comment: ' if the "Winner" Defect passed retest, now "Loser" can retest which should be green in color , i have multiple Loser defect id associated to one id separated with (,), so if Winner is passed i need to make all loser to green color End Sub...

Comment: People seem to hate [conditional formatting](https://www.google.hu/search?client=opera&q=conditional+formatting&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)... :(

Comment: @Vacip: as my sheet gets created a fresh every time, more over i am new to macro and conditional formatting, but if you have a reference please pass it , i will try it out. 

I need to mark color a different color  as per below condition,
if the "Winner" Defect passed retest, now "Loser" can retest which should be green in color , i have multiple Loser defect id associated to one id separated with (,), so if Winner is passed i need to make all loser to green color End Sub

Comment: I don't see a question...

Comment: @Davesexcel, my apologies. 
Question is : i need a logic 
1.where i can get the status of a defect from Column F, 
2.If the status is retested and passed then i need to see if there are any values in Column C, Duplicate ID( there may have multiple id separated with comma(,)
3.I need to take individual values and search in Column A , ex. for defect ID , JIRA1 there are 2 duplicate id ALM3 and ALM7. so i need to look for those values in Column A Defect id. 
4.If the status of those defects (ALM3 and ALM7) is NOT closed then i need to mark the entire row in Green color. as per the screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

I am interpreting your comments to mean:

1. Column I contains information regarding the current status. It will have certain key words such as "Closed", "New", "blocked", "Open". Now, you have a new key word "Passed" (I am guessing).
2. Each key word will have a corresponding color that is used to highlight some of the cells in the same row. In the case of the new key word "Passed", you want the color to be Green.

And I am interpreting your question to be: **How do I modify the code I already have, to make the cell colors green when I find the key word "Passed"?**

Your code, modified to address *that* question, is below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("I2:I250")
    For Each cell In rng
    Select Case cell.Offset(0, 0).Value
       Case "Closed"
           cell.Resize(1, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
       Case "New"
           cell.Resize(1, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 31
       Case "blocked"
           cell.Resize(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 50
       Case "open"
           cell.Resize(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
       Case "Passed"
           cell.Resize(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
       Case Else
           cell.Resize(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
       End Select
     Next
 ' if the "Winner" Defect passed retest, now "Loser" can retest which should be green in color , i havee multiple Losed defect id associated to one id separated with (,), so if Winner is passed i need to make all loser to green color
End Sub
```

I choose the number 4 to represent green based on the default color palette [as documented by MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840443.aspx). Since you already are using the number 4 for "Closed", you may already be highlighting with green, or you may be using a customized color palette.

Comment: What i need is to find the duplicate id in C column in row 1 and mark it with a color.1.Where i can get the status of a defect from Column F,  2.If the status is retested and passed then i need to see if there are any values in Column C, Duplicate ID( there may have multiple id separated with comma(,)  3.I need to take individual values and search in Column A ,ex. for defect ID , JIRA1 there are 2 duplicate id ALM3 and ALM7. so i need to look for those values in Column A Defect id. 
4.If the status of those defects (ALM3 and ALM7) is NOT closed then i need to mark the entire row in Green color

Comment: i am got answer for few just i need to how to put this logic....
    if Range("F2:F565") =" ready to retest" then 
    pick value from ("D2:D565"),
    Split the value ("D2:D5655")
    find the splited value in ("A2:A565") high light with a green color
    end if

Comment: Can any of the admin remove on hold status???? i need help here very badly....thanks in advance

Comment: @Venkat - your question is on hold because it is too broad, and now it is morphing. If you now have a more focused question, it is worth posting a new explicit question, following the rules of [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)